# What is equivalent of "export type" of TypeScript in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a script based on an Medium article to learn something new, but in the guide he uses TypeScript. I am trying to use JavaScript equivalent things, but I am in doubt with something, he says to use `export type`, but how can I use this in JavaScript codes?

```
export type CovidStateResponse = {
  state: string
  updated: number
  cases: number
  todayCases: number
  deaths: number
  todayDeaths: number
  active: number
  casesPerOneMillion: number
  deathsPerOneMillion: number
  tests: number
  testsPerOneMillion: number
  population: number
}
export type CovidStatesResponse = CovidStateResponse[]
```

Comment: Javascript does not have custom typings, so you should be good to go if you ignore the types part of the article's code. Also, can you link me the article, it seems like it's using my api [disease.sh](https://disease.sh)

Comment: @EliteDaMyth So I just have to ignore the type part?

Comment: Another way to say it: types get removed from the code when TypeScript is transpiled into JavaScript, so yes, just ignore it

Comment: Thank you, if you want you can post an answer for me to check as correct. Just for organization.

Comment: @EliteDaMyth https://medium.com/teamzerolabs/write-aprometheus-api-exporter-in-record-time-7518ee22f238